# Как в Regex получить данные по ограниченному количеству символов?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

помогите пожалуйста. Как мне в регулярном выражении получить данные по ограниченному количеству символов?

Имеется вот такой пример в песочнице

https://regex101.com/r/RrU8Td/4

```html
regex

(^|\s)@

---------
text

text @user text @Губка Боб text @user1 text text @SiteTe.ru text text text @любитель text text @guba bob text text @geb 123
```

Необходимо получить следующие значения с ограничением по 30 символам

```html
@user text @Губка Боб text @us
@Губка Боб text @user1 text te
@user1 text text @SiteTe.ru te
@SiteTe.ru text text text @люб
@любитель text text @guba bob 
@guba bob text text @geb 123 t
@geb 123 text
```

Update

да то что нужно! Спасибо! подскажите только как теперь сделать чтобы в matches[0] были значения

```html
@user text @Губка Боб text @us
@Губка Боб text @user1 text te
@user1 text text @SiteTe.ru te
@SiteTe.ru text text text @люб
@любитель text text @guba bob 
@guba bob text text @geb 123
@geb 123
```

а в matches[1]

```html
user text @Губка Боб text @us
Губка Боб text @user1 text te
user1 text text @SiteTe.ru te
SiteTe.ru text text text @люб
любитель text text @guba bob 
guba bob text text @geb 123
geb 123
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/RrU8Td/5

Comment: У вас "опечатка" в последней строке, `@geb 123 text`, а  должно быть `@geb 123`, да?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
if (preg_match_all('~(?=(?<!\S)(@.{0,29}))~u', $text, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
```

См. [пример работы кода](https://3v4l.org/jRDVS) и [регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/OOImbD/1). Подробности:

- `(?=` - начало блока предварительного просмотра вперёд:

  - `(?<!\S)` - блок предварительного просмотра назад, который проверяет наличие пробельного символа или начала строки сразу перед текущей позицией
  - `(@.{0,29})` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: `@` и затем 0-29 символов, отличных от перевода строки, как можно больше
- `)` - конец блока предварительного просмотра вперёд

Результат:

```
@user text @Губка Боб text @us
@Губка Боб text @user1 text te
@user1 text text @SiteTe.ru te
@SiteTe.ru text text text @люб
@любитель text text @guba bob 
@guba bob text text @geb 123
@geb 123
```

Comment: да то что нужно! Спасибо огромное! Только можно еще небольшие правки? обновил первый пост Update

Comment: раньше просто такая логика была

Comment: @Vlad Это невозможно, так как для перекрещивающихся совпадений необходимо использовать захватывающую подмаску внутри позитивного предварительного блока просмотра вперёд.

Comment: @Vlad Если очень надо, то вы можете использовать `array_shift($matches)`, а затем `print_r($matches[0])`. См. [демо](https://3v4l.org/bKRtI).